# One or two words replacement

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for the shortest, 1 max 2 words replacement for the following words

> “A product of rape”

It is a part of the sentence:

> A product of rape, now a DREAMer, writes to the man who…

Comment: You would say *victim* of rape, or *rape victim*, or *rape survivor*, or just *survivor*.

Comment: Why does it have to be one or two words? What's wrong with clarifying, and being unambiguous? A person who survived a rape attack/ who was [conceived by rape](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=conceived+in+by+rape)

Comment: @Mari-Lou A  It is a logline, so less is more. Areel got the right answer-solution for me.

Comment: Then you should accept the answer. Click on the grey checkmark beneath the arrow. It's only visible to you, the OP.

Comment: Why is *dreamer* written as DREAMer? No one seems to be asking, so I must be the dumb one round here.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A
“Click on the grey checkmark” – Sorry, didn’t know that.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A
“Why is dreamer written as DREAMer?”
Because it is how one writes it:  
https://www.google.si/search?num=100&q=dreamer+in+usa&oq=dreamer+in+usa&gs_l=serp.3..0i19k1j0i22i30i19k1.11706.12905.0.13129.7.7.0.0.0.0.212.1241.0j5j2.7.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.7.1236...0j0i67k1j0i22i30k1j0i22i10i30i19k1.D4BrT5vDHgM

Comment: If I am quoting John Lennon's song Imagine, I'd write it as *dreamer*, what I was really asking about was its meaning. P.S I'm not an American citizen, and you might be surprised to hear that many users on EL&U aren't. You know, if you edited your question and explained *why* you needed a single-word solution, and perhaps embedded a link to [DREAMer](http://thehill.com/blogs/congress-blog/education/181607-who-are-the-qdreamersq), I'd upvote your question.

Comment: And I bet other users would too as well, upvote your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand 'a product of rape' to mean someone who was conceived as a result of their mother suffering rape. How about 'Rape-begotten'?

Comment: I would scream - a genius - unfortunately, I can only write it. Thanks for your solution - you are a genius - and 100% right with the "product of rape." Would it be correct "A rape-begot, now a DREAMer - or A rape-begotten, now a DREAMer, writes to the man, who...?" She is a girl.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are referring to the person who was raped.  If so, you could refer to them as "a victim."  They can also be called "a survivor."  In either case, I suggest you use "one" followed by the word:

> One [victim/survivor], now a DREAMer...

This works if it is clear they are a victim of rape (and not of some other crime).  If it is ambiguous, you have to include "rape" before the term.

> One rape [victim/survivor], now a DREAMer...

Comment: Areel got it right with her answer. It is a result of rape, a daughter.

Comment: @Syk no, Areel guessed what and who you were talking about because you didn't clarify. Less is not more if it is ambiguous. If I suffer post traumatic stress disorder (PTSD), in a sense I am a "product" of that trauma.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A In a screenplay, less is always more. A simple search confirms it:
https://www.google.si/search?num=100&biw=1089&bih=840&q=product+of+a+rape&oq=product+of+a+rape&gs_l=serp.12..0i22i30i19k1.511562.511562.0.512600.1.1.0.0.0.0.333.333.3-1.1.0....0...1c.2.64.serp..0.1.333.ErqatWbd6z0  

A product is a result, the finished work. Anything else could be a victim, observer, witness, survivor, copycat…, but never a product. Trauma, for instance, could be considered a consequence, but not a product.

Comment: @Syk that may be so, but on EL&U detail and clarification is appreciated and is helpful to readers and visitors alike. Please note that another user posted in the comments "victim" and "survivor". Brevity is not always foolproof.

Comment: It would seem to be adding insult to injury, even for a fictional character, to define their whole existence in terms of them having suffered rape. On the other hand, it was obvious to me that if  you were conceived as a result of your mother suffering rape, you are, by definition, a product of rape.

Comment: @Areel Xocha It works for a logline because a logline is meant only for the producer to incite him/her to order the script.   A logline should not be written too much on the nose. It is preferred to hide the direct meanings of your plot, storyline and its end.   That is why I have used DREAMer; a product of rape… all that combined with the title will help the producer to figure out who the rapist is even before he orders the script.

Comment: @Marie-Lou A “I'm not an American citizen” – I have noticed that through your usage of “grey” instead of “gray.” The thing is, you have such limitations on this forum when it comes to the number of words/letters per post and the overcomplicated editing of one’s posts that I try to keep everything to a minimum and add details later if necessary.